# ChildNode with Alpha higher than parent

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an area of my game that acts as a semi transparent background for a bunch of things on top of it. I set the alpha of the background to 0.7 (since I want to see underneath this)

Now, I created a bunch of sprite nodes that are the child of this semi transparent background which is inheriting the alpha from the parent (background). Is there anyway I can stop that?

Code Example:

```
_cardAreaBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background_cardarea"];
[_cardAreaBackground setName:kCardAreaBackgroundKeyword];
[_cardAreaBackground setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[_cardAreaBackground setPosition:CGPointMake([self determineCardAreaBackgroundX],         [_infoBarBackground size].height)];
[_cardAreaBackground setZPosition:10];
[_cardAreaBackground setAlpha:0.3];
[self addChild:_cardAreaBackground];

SKSpriteNode *drawPile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"card_back"];
[drawPile setName:kCardAreaBackgroundKeyword];
[drawPile setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[drawPile setPosition:CGPointMake( 120 + 1954, 10 )];
[drawPile setZPosition:11];
[drawPile setScale:0.3125];
[_cardAreaBackground addChild:drawPile];
```

You can see what I am trying to do above. If this is not the correct way to do this, please let me know. The reason I am doing this I actually have 3 sections in this "card background area" that the user can swipe between where I want different things to be visible on there.

Comment: Instead of setting alpha try setting the background color with alpha, it should work -
`[_cardAreaBackground setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]]`

Instead of `[UIColor whiteColor]`, you can give your desired color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting alpha try setting the background color with alpha, it should work -

```
[_cardAreaBackground setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]]
```

Instead of [UIColor whiteColor], you can give your desired color.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make the background as well as the child sprites the children on another sprite. So, the background will not affect the nodes on top of it.

```
_cardTable = [SKNode new];

_cardAreaBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background_cardarea"];
[_cardAreaBackground setName:kCardAreaBackgroundKeyword];
[_cardAreaBackground setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[_cardAreaBackground setZPosition:10];
[_cardAreaBackground setAlpha:0.3];
[cardTable addChild:_cardAreaBackground];

SKSpriteNode *drawPile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"card_back"];
[drawPile setName:kCardAreaBackgroundKeyword];
[drawPile setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[drawPile setPosition:CGPointMake( 120 + 1954, 10 )];
[drawPile setZPosition:11];
[drawPile setScale:0.3125];
[cardTable addChild:drawPile];

[cardTable setPosition:CGPointMake([self determineCardAreaBackgroundX],         [_infoBarBackground size].height)];

[self addChild:cardTable];
```

Comment: This answer should have been selected. Nice solution.